# Merging remote branch into folder

Tags: git, merge

There is a repository `OTHER` with 2 branches `master` and `b1`

I was interested only in `master` branch of `OTHER`

So, there is my repository `MY` witch 2 branches `master` and `other_import`

I added a `remote` in `MY` repo pointing to the `OTHER` called `upstream`

Now when I want to get latest changes of `OTHER`'s `master` I do:

`git checkout other_import`

`git fetch --all`

`git merge upstream/master`

then merge my `master` changes in and merge `other_import` into my `master`

So far it worked well.

`OTHER` repository has following folder structure:

```
OTHER
  |-F1
  |-F2
```

is was fine, so since the first merge, I've been working in structure like this

```
MY
  |-F1
  |-F2
  |-Project
```

But now I needed to change the structure like so:

```
MY
  |-WrappedOther
    |-F1
    |-F2
  |-Project
```

so on I did `git mv ...`

But now, I'm not sure how to merge `OTHER` into `MY` without getting lots of conflict about moved files every time...

Is there a way to merge remote branch into a folder?

Something like:

`git merge upstream/master WrappedOther`

Or how should I merge it?

Comment: (I'm well aware of similar questions on SO, but I find them not to be exactly the same as mine)

Answer (score 0):

This is now a perfect use case for using the `OTHER` as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Basically, the other project now gets added to your original project as a submodule, and then you can accordingly fetch changes from `upstream` into `OTHER`, while fetching changes of your `project` on to your `feature` branch.

The only issue could be if you were modifying code from `OTHER` project - In which case, the migration of commit will be a task.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git merge --strategy subtree upstream/master`. Should give less conflicts.

See the strategy description in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html